# Split a list into multiple ones

Tags: python, list, split

I am trying to split a list into multiple ones. The original list `lst` should be split on every element that is present in a second list, `split_on`.

Example:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
split_on = [3, 4, 7]
```

should yield:

```
[[1,2,3],[3,4],[4,5,6,7],[7,8]]
```

Note that both `lst` and `split_on` do not contain duplicate elements and that any item of `split_on` is also an item of `lst`. Finally, the order of the elements of `split_on` can be random.

Answer (score 2):

How about the following:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
b = [4,3,7]

res = [[]]
for i in a:
    res[-1].append(i)
    if i in b:
        res.append([i])

print(res)  # [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8]]
```

Note that since `b` is only used for membership tests and the order does not matter, you could consider converting it to a `set` so that the approach scales better.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is great !